# How to explain the Coordinate system on Android animation?

Tags: android, animation, coordinate-systems

As we know , the android coordinate system is start from the top left corner of the android screen. The x-axis is down growth and the y-axis is right growth.But I found it's not right for the animation.

For example, I initialized the TranslateAnimation using the constructed function:

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200, 0.0f, 200);
```

Does the coordinate system have changed ? I found it didn't start from the top left corner.

Then I initialized the other translateAnimation for moving up and right direction :

```
TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 200, 0.0f, -200); 
ta.setReaptMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

The same behavior would be found.
I am confused about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that constructor for TranslateAnimation uses deltas. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29). Or look at the constructor sig. : `(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)`. So if you want your anim. to jump *up* first, you could use a negative third ctor param.

More precisely:

An animation can never start until after the layout has been [measured](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29). One usually shouldn't have to worry about how this works beyond that the algorithm is mostly very good and you can take control of its strategies by setting [layout parameters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). In short, by the time an animation might be started, we know where *you* want the view to be on the screen, because you set layout parameters.

Translate animation then takes deltas from *that position*. So your current animation shouldn't start from the top left, but rather wherever those layout params were evaluated by onMeasure.

Some would say- how annoying. It's gonna get complicated even if you just want to do some simple up-down type animations... Well, here's an advisable development strategy; it snould make android animation development a breeeze. Set an [`animationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) on every animation. In onAnimationEnd, in possibly a parametized way, *reset* the layout parameters on the view your animating to where you *expect* it to be. That way, you'll get no surprising "jumps" when you re-apply an animation again. You may need to `invalidate` in some circumstances, or `clearAnimation`. The reason that this works is that the measure pass will be caused to come round again and you'll have a new offset for your `TranslateAnimation`. Finally, you may want to do all this resetting posted to the message queue of a view using `post(Runnable runnable)` in the listener, so you're off the last pass of the animation draw.

I too found android Animations can occasionally surprise you and cause jumpy behaviour. But if you do it like this, constructors taking delta params shouldn't be confusing again.